# Android how to design the xml about the UI

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I need to design the xml about below layout.

[image]

I try to use RelativeLayout to design, but I don't know

how to adjust the imageVivew3 in RelativeLayout.

Have anyone can teach me how to adjust the xml?

or have you nice xml  design about this layout?

thank you very much.

my xml is below:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relative_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:visibility="visible"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
           android:visibility="visible"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           />


<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageView4"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="txt1"
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="@dimen/common_size_large"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="txt2"
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout..
And also use **android:layout_weight** atttribute ...code sample are given below... put this 
code to your xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/gerder"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:fontFamily="@string/providerFontFamily"
                />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGender"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/providerGenderMale"
                android:checked="true" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/providerGenderFemale" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@string/providerFontFamily"
            android:text="@string/age_range"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I dont use linearlayout, because my imageview1,2,3 have overlap part, so I think to use relativelayout

Comment: Its not seems overlapped your images w.r.o your screen short... @dickfala

Comment: sorry, I meaning the imageview2 and imageview 3 horizontal have overlap. The imageview1, 2, 3 have overlay in vertical .

Comment: can you try to write the imageview1~3 sample for me about use linearlayout? thank you very much..@Amitabha Biswas

Comment: sorry @dickfala ... its occured probleam...Images are showing one after another...

Comment: oh oh.. /~\ So I think use relativelayout, but i don't know how to set in imageview3